# Android - app crashes when using get.Width()

Tags: android

I have **xml file:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Cell"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rect"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/tvText"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:gravity="center_vertical"
 android:minHeight="40dp"
 android:text="">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is rectangle 50x50 with empty TextView.

I try to get this Width in **my custom method**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    ..............
    }

public void MyMethod(View v) {
     int CellWidth = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Cell)).getWidth();
     //Toast.makeText(this, CellWidth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

It is no errors in Eclipse, but my app crashes on this.

**BUT:** If I manually add Cell on the screen, before using MyMethod, then this **string works**.

```
int CellWidth = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Cell)).getWidth();
```

But if i add **toast**:

```
Toast.makeText(this, CellWidth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

... then app crushes again.

What am I doing wrong?

## Update

Thanks **Szymon** for help in solving the Toast problem.

Now I have **this code**:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);      
        Field = new GridView(this);
        Test = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Test);
        // Create the Custom Adapter Object
        FieldAdapter = new FieldAdapter(this);
        // Set the Adapter to GridView
        Field.setAdapter(FieldAdapter);

}

public void MyMethod(View v) {
            Field.setNumColumns(GridView.AUTO_FIT);
            Test.addView(Field);
            int CellWidth = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Cell)).getWidth();
            Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(CellWidth), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

As you can see, I **add my GridView** (which contains Cell.xml as layout for every cell) **to the screen**:

```
Test.addView(Field);
```

And **after** that I try to getWidth() of Cell. Still not working.

But, if I will do it in other method with time delay - it works. Here is LogCat:

```
04-27 17:23:10.861: E/Trace(7482): error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
04-27 17:23:10.861: D/ActivityThread(7482): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
04-27 17:23:10.861: D/ActivityThread(7482): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
04-27 17:23:10.861: D/ActivityThread(7482): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
04-27 17:23:10.971: D/libEGL(7482): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
04-27 17:23:10.971: D/libEGL(7482): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
04-27 17:23:10.971: D/libEGL(7482): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
04-27 17:23:10.991: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(7482): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-27 17:23:11.001: E/(7482): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
04-27 17:23:11.011: E/(7482): <s3dReadConfigFile:75>: Can't open file for reading
04-27 17:23:11.051: D/OpenGLRenderer(7482): Enabling debug mode 0
04-27 17:23:11.161: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7482): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-27 17:23:11.161: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(7482): clearMetaKeyStates on inactive InputConnection
04-27 17:23:15.465: D/AndroidRuntime(7482): Shutting down VM
04-27 17:23:15.465: W/dalvikvm(7482): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d66438)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3598)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4091)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17036)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:558)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3593)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     ... 11 more
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     at com.example.field.MainActivity.CreateGrid(MainActivity.java:35)
04-27 17:23:15.475: E/AndroidRuntime(7482):     ... 14 more
04-27 17:23:16.807: I/Process(7482): Sending signal. PID: 7482 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post the logcat where you are getting errors

Comment: Here is in my post (after UPDATE header)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the toast like that, you call this overload of `makeText` of `Toast` class because the second parameter (`CellWidth`) is of `int` type:

```
makeText(Context context, int resId, int duration)
```

As a resource with the id which equals to your width doesn't exist, the app crashes.

You want to use this overload to display a string:

```
makeText(Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

You can do it this way:

```
Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(CellWidth), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```